# Two balls are drawn from an urn - only reporting "red" if one of the two is red. What if only one is drawn?

Tags: probability

A second party draws a ball from an urn, then replaces it. Then a second ball is drawn. If at least one ball is red they report "red".
After a million trials they report red 12% of the time.

What is the probability of drawing a red ball if only 1 ball is drawn?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Suppose the probability of drawing red was $p=.2$.  What would be the probability of someone reporting "red" in your game?

Comment: 1- (4/5)*(4/5)
So 36%?

Comment: Sure...though I see someone has posted a full solution, which looks complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this by looking at the complement: Let $p$ denote the probability of drawing a black ball from the urn. The probability of drawing two black balls is then $p^2 = .88$.  Once you solve for $p$, the probability of drawing a red ball is $1-p$.

Comment: Thank you. That made sense.
I was struggling because in the real life situation there are 123 colors of balls and I didn't realize that we could just look for "non red"